# Bazel macro fails with `name 'glob' is not defined`

Tags: macros, bazel

I defined a Bazel macro. It looks something like this:

```py
def my_macro():
    java_binary(
        srcs = glob(["*.java"])
        # ...
    )
```

When I run Bazel, it fails with an error

```
ERROR: /home/.../macros.bzl:105:19: name 'glob' is not defined
```

Is it possible to use `glob` in a macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`glob`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#glob) function is only available in BUILD.bazel files. In macro definitions in a `.bzl` file, access it as [`native.glob`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/native.html#glob).

```py
def my_macro():
    java_binary(
        srcs = native.glob(["*.java"])
        # ...
    )
```

References: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/sXa60DnjxiA